# Finding Personal ID contour after Canny Edge Detection - OpenCV 4.0 + Python

Tags: opencv, image-processing, ocr, edge-detection

I am trying to find Personal ID in image and obtain birds view of it by following this tutorial: https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2014/09/01/build-kick-ass-mobile-document-scanner-just-5-minutes/. Problem is that I cannot seem to find contour that has 4 points.

Few things come to mind. First of all, personal ID has rounded angles, so I am guessing that might be one of the issues. Second, after preprocessing the image I get something like this:
[image]

So I guess that maybe some further preprocessing might be needed. I tried to erode and dilate image in order to try to get rid of the noise and fill in the gaps of contour that represents personal ID, but no luck.

Any suggestions would be appreciated. Thank you!

**NOTE**: *I am using OpenCV 4.0 and Python for this project.*

Comment: Sharing your input as well would help a lot